Errors when trying to run and setup rustlings
While following the steps on the Rustlings website, I encountered an error: terminal output. I simply ran the provided command as instructed, without altering anything. How can I resolve this issue? I'm unsure what caused it since I followed the setup exactly as described on the site. Is there a specific configuration or dependency I might have missed? My goal is to get Rustlings running properly, but this error is preventing me from proceeding. Any guidance on troubleshooting or resolving this would be appreciated!
terminal output:
•   fastfetch
PNG         コンピューター
        ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
           OS : CachyOS Linux x86_64
           Kernel : Linux 6.12.3-1-cachyos
           Packages : 2082 (pacman), 17 (flatpak-system), 29 (flatpak-user)
           Display : 1920x1080 @ 100 Hz in 24" [External]
           Display : 1920x1080 @ 165 Hz in 27" [External] *
           WM : Mutter (Wayland)
           Terminal : foot 1.19.0
        └──────────────────────────────────────────┘

           : pizzav@cachyos
        ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
           CPU : 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12600KF
           GPU : GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate
           GPU Driver : nvidia (proprietary) 565.77
           Memory : 13.42 GiB / 31.16 GiB (43%)
           OS Age  : 94 days
           Uptime  : 42 mins
        └──────────────────────────────────────────┘
          ● ● ● ● ● ● ● ●

 0s •• ••/  /rust  •  mast 
•   rustlings init
This command will create the directory `rustlings/` which will contain the exercises.
Press ENTER to continue  

Initialization done ✓

Run `cd rustlings` to go into the generated directory.
Then run `rustlings` to get started.
 1s •• ••/  /rust  •  mast 
•   cd rustlings/
 0s •• ••/rustlings  •  mast 
•   rustlings
error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/pizzav/Documents/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
Error: The command `cargo metadata …` failed. Are you in the `rustlings/` directory?


delete /home/pizzav/Documents/Cargo.toml
